# Check insecure connection with script

Tags: tls, openssl, tls-intercept

I'm checking connections that traffic data in plain text, example: **http://**site.com
but I'd like to check with some script.
Does anyone know any scripts or how I can use openssl to find out if a website has a secure connection?
I don't want to use a browser to know if the script has https or not
I tried with testssl, but they don't show this information.

Comment: You could use `curl`, `nmap`, `wget`, `opennssl s_client`...

Comment: Yes. I can use command curl, nmao and openssl s_clent.

Comment: ThoriumBR, you can help me?

Comment: `curl -sk https://example.com > /dev/null && echo Site acessible via HTTPS || echo Site not accessible via HTTPS`